# MYSQL Getting Data too many connections in-spite of closing resources properly

Tags: java, connection-pooling

I am using mysql 5.0 and i am frequently getting Data too many connections error , and i am sure that i am closing all the connections inside my finally block

This is my class for obtaining DataBase connection

```
public class DBConnection {

    final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(DBConnection.class);
     private static DataSource dataSource;
        static {
            try {
                  dataSource = (DataSource) new InitialContext().lookup("java:/comp/env/jdbc/REDEX");
            } catch (NamingException e) {
                logger.error("NamingException Occured" , e);
                e.printStackTrace();
                try {
                  //  throw new Exception("'jndifordbconc' not found in JNDI",e);

                } catch (Exception e1) {

                    //logger.error("Exception Occured" , e1);
                    logger.error("NamingException Occured" , e1);
                        e1.printStackTrace();

                }
            }
        }

        public static Connection getDBConnection() {
            try {
                return dataSource.getConnection();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                logger.error("Exception Occured Under getDBConnection" , e);
                return null;
            }

        }


    public static void close(Connection con)
    {
        if (con != null)
        {
            try
            {
                con.close();
            }
            catch (SQLException e)
            {
                logger.error("Exception Occured inside close " , e);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void close(Statement stmt, ResultSet rs) 
    {
        if (rs != null)
        {
            try
            {
                rs.close();
            }
            catch (SQLException e)
            {
                logger.error("Exception Occured while closing resultset " , e);
            }
        }
        if (stmt != null)
        {
            try
            {
                stmt.close();
            }
            catch (SQLException e)
            {
                logger.error("Exception Occured while closing statement " , e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Connection pooling settings**

```
<ResourceLink name="jdbc/REDEX"
                global="jdbc/REDEX"
                type="javax.sql.DataSource" />

<Resource name="jdbc/REDEX"
      global="jdbc/REDEX"
      type="javax.sql.DataSource"
      auth="Container"
      driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
      url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/REDEX?allowMultiQueries=true"
     factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
      username="root"
      password="xxxxx@123"
    initialSize="100"
      maxActive="100"
      maxIdle="20"
     minIdle="10"
    suspectTimeout="60"
    timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="30000"
    minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="60000"
   validationQuery="SELECT 1"
   validationInterval="34000"
  testOnBorrow="true"
   removeAbandoned="true"
  removeAbandonedTimeout="55"
  />
```

Sample java class how am i using the connection and closing

```
public class GetBrands {
    final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(GetBrands.class);
    @GET
    @Consumes("application/text")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public String getAllBrands() throws JSONException 
    {
        logger.error("the GetBrands got called");
        Connection dbConnection = null;
        PreparedStatement getAllBrandsPst = null ;
        ResultSet getAllBrandsResltSet = null;
        JSONArray jsonarray_listedBrands = new JSONArray();
        JSONObject jsonObj_allbrands = new JSONObject();
        try
        {
            dbConnection = DBConnectionOrient.getDBConnection();
            getAllBrandsPst = dbConnection.prepareStatement("select distinct listedBrandName,listedbrandID from tbl_listedBrand  group by listedBrandName");
            getAllBrandsResltSet = getAllBrandsPst.executeQuery();
            while(getAllBrandsResltSet.next())
            {
                //
            }
            jsonObj_allbrands.put("brands", jsonarray_listedBrands);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            logger.error("Exception Occured" , e);
        }
        finally
        {
            DBConnectionOrient.close(getAllBrandsPst,getAllBrandsResltSet);
            DBConnectionOrient.close(dbConnection);
        }

        String  response = "jsonCallback("+jsonObj_allbrands.toString()+")";
        return response;
    }
}
```

This is the exception i am getting in logs

```
SEVERE: Unable to create initial connections of pool.
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Data source rejected establishment of connection,  message from server: "Too many connections"
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1014)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:988)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:974)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1110)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2465)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2498)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2283)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:822)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor10.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:404)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:317)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:278)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:182)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:701)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:635)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:486)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:144)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:116)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:103)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory.createDataSource(DataSourceFactory.java:554)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory.getObjectInstance(DataSourceFactory.java:242)
    at org.apache.naming.factory.ResourceFactory.getObjectInstance(ResourceFactory.java:141)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:321)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:842)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:153)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:830)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.addResource(NamingContextListener.java:1103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.createNamingContext(NamingContextListener.java:682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.lifecycleEvent(NamingContextListener.java:271)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:689)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:321)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:455)
```

If there are multiple can i follow this way

```
finally {
    try {
        DBConnectionOrient.close(getAllBrandsPst,getAllBrandsResltSet);
 DBConnectionOrient.close(getAllBrandsPst2,getAllBrandsResltSet2);
    } catch (Exception e) {}
    try {
        DBConnectionOrient.close(dbConnection);
    } catch (Exception e) {}
}
```

Comment: Are there any exceptions in your log which particularly stand out?  This might give you a good hook into the code you have given above.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen , thanks , i have edited my question and posted the exception stack trace i am getting .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see one potential problem with your code which *might* be the source of some unclosed dangling database connections.  I draw your attention to the following 2 lines of code:

```
DBConnectionOrient.close(getAllBrandsPst,getAllBrandsResltSet);
DBConnectionOrient.close(dbConnection);
```

Recognize that if an exception occurs during the first call to `DBConnectionOrient.close()` for the statement and result set, then the database connection will never be closed.  A safer way of doing this is the following:

```
finally {
    try {
        DBConnectionOrient.close(getAllBrandsPst,getAllBrandsResltSet);
    } catch (Exception e) {}
    try {
        DBConnectionOrient.close(dbConnection);
    } catch (Exception e) {}
}
```

Now, even if something goes wrong with closing the statement and result set, an attempt to close the database connection will still be made.

Here is the general meme you should follow with your JDBC calls:

```
Connection con = null;
Statement stmt = null;
ResultSet rs = null;

try {
    // get a connection, statement and result set, in this order
    // make your JDBC calls here
} catch (Exception e) {
    // handle all exceptions here
} finally {
     try {
         try {rs.close();} catch (Exception e) {}
         try {stmt.close();} catch (Exception e) {}
          // Note that we will attempt to close the database connection even
          // if something went wrong with closing the statement or result set
         try {con.close();} catch (Exception e) {}
     } catch (Exception e) {  }
}
```

Comment: but i am doing the sam ething under DBConnection.close methods know

Comment: No, you're not.  If an exception happens on the first call to `close()` then then database won't be closed.

Comment: Well don't take my word for it.  Try out the fix I suggested, and keep your eyes open for other problems.  If I fixed your problem, then show me some green.  If not, then come back and update with your findings.

Comment: please see my edited question , if there are mutiple then can i folow the above way ??

Comment: That is _OK_ provided you realize that once any exception happens, then no other statements/result sets will be closed.  But yes, this should solve the database problem assuming my hunch be correct.  A better way would be to follow the framework in my answer when handling your JDBC resources.  Keep it safe and simple.

Comment: One final comment: You should still try to find out why you were getting exceptions when trying to close statements and result sets.  But glad to hear that at least you are running more smoothly now.